# How to change the Meta Title of a Category Archive into a custom ACF field?

Tags: php, wordpress

In WooCommerce:
The meta title for archive categories is to be changed to a a custom ACF field. I have added the field in the back end to the category admin pages and I am able to save the custom field.

I use elementor.

I am unable to change the meta title to a custom field.

What code can be entered in functions.php of my theme such that if the archive page is a category, and the custom act field exists, then the meta title should be the custom ACF field saved for that category?

I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53578989/replace-woocommerce-taxonomy-archive-pages-title-with-acf-custom-field) but yet couldn’t complete the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
function custom_document_title( $title ) {
    $queried_object = get_queried_object(); 

    if ( ! $queried_object ) {
        return $title;
    }

    $taxonomy = $queried_object->taxonomy;
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;

    if ( is_product_category() && get_field( 'acf_field_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id ) ) {
        return get_field( 'acf_field_name', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id );
    }

    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_document_title', 'custom_document_title', 10, 1 );
```

Tested & Working

Comment: This solution is 100% working and the code is neat.

Comment: How can i perform the same for archive product brand?
Should i change is_product_category to is_tax( 'product_brand' ) ?

Comment: Hello @ArpanJain , use it like this : ` is_product_category('product_brand') `

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75600599

This is related but not yet answered.